# How to import MySQL from main app.py file? circular import issue

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

How to add MySQL config to Flask app and create cursor and use in other classes?

I have 2 files:

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from Query import Query
from flask_mysqldb impoty MySQL

app= Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

api.add_resouce(Query,'/')

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'host'
#(same for user, password, db)

mysql = MySQL(app)
```

Query.py:

I am trying to import mysql FROM app.py so I can execute SQL on my DB.

```
 from flask_restfull import Resource
 from app import mysql 

class Query(Resource):
    def get(self):
    pass
```

Error is caused by circular import. How to fix it?

"cannot import name 'Query'

Answer (score 1):

Initialize mysql in another file, and reference it from both `query.py` and `app.py`. Inject it into the app using `MySQL.init_app` method

https://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_mysqldb.MySQL

```py
# database.py
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
mysql = MySQL()
```

```py
# query.py
from database import mysql # <--!!!
from flask_restfull import Resource

class Query(Resource):
    def get(self):
        pass
```

```py
# app.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from database import mysql # <--!!!
from query import Query

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
api.add_resouce(Query,'/')
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'host'

mysql.init_app(app) # <--!!!
```